# MVVM,DataBinding,retrofit and recyclerview

Tags: mvvm, android-recyclerview, data-binding, retrofit, android-databinding

For example, I have a model class name movies and I am fetching the list of movies from an api
and I got `List<movies> list` then I pass this list in recycler view and triggered `notifydatasetchanged()`.

Thenmy question is to bind the data in the XML Should I have to expose my model class for databinding. Is this a correct mvvm pattern?
How can I achieve it by binding my XML to `ViewModel` class?

Comment: Just making it clear that i want to ask how to provide ViewModel to the binding in case of Recycer view

Answer (score 1):

You can use data binging for your recycler view.
You can add:

```xml
<data><variable name="movie" type="com.example.myproject.model.Movie"/>
</data>
```

tag to your recycler view row item XML layout.

Then inside the `View Holder` class you can implement binding method like this

```
public void binding(Movie movie){
  movieRowBinding.setMovie(movie);
  movieRowBinding.executePendingBindings();
}
```